# a shellcode to get the shell,but segment default happened

Tags: linux, shellcode

Let me just show you my code first.

```
char shellcode[] =    
"\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
"\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
"\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";


int main()
{

int *ret;
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
(*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

it is a shell-spawning shellcode,the code is coming from a book-- " shellcoder's handbook".i just copy the code in the book,and compiled it with gcc(gcc shellcode.c -o shellcode).and my gcc version is 4.7.2,my machine is X86 ,but i run it on debian ,i just get segmentation fault.

output of readelf -l  is:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x80482f0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x08048134 0x08048134 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x0050c 0x0050c R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00050c 0x0804950c 0x0804950c 0x00134 0x00138 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x000518 0x08049518 0x08049518 0x000f0 0x000f0 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000148 0x08048148 0x08048148 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000490 0x08048490 0x08048490 0x0001c 0x0001c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .hash .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr             .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr   .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07
```

all right,is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute code located on the stack, yet your stack is not executable.

```
GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
```

You defintely want to link using the **-z execstack** switch. And just to be sure, disable stack protection manually at compile time : **-fno-stack-protector**

You final gcc command line should be :

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shellcode.c -o shellcode
```

PS: You might want to read the gcc man page, these flags are pretty well documented.

Comment: sorry,my english is so bad,maybe i did not express it clearly.

Comment: OK,let me give you more information.the code is comming from a book-- " shellcoder's handbook".i just copy the code in the book,and compiled it with gcc.and it is a shell-spawning shellcode,but i run it on my debian ,i just get segmentation fault .

Comment: hello?i hava all the info in the main post

Comment: I tried the same command with the `z execstack` option, now I see `RWE` under `GNU_STACK` header. However, when I run the binary, nothing happens. It's expected to spawn a shell.